# PHP OOP which design pattern use

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have two classes and I need to use best OOP design solution.

```
class Dogs extends Animals {
   CONST TABLE = 'dogs';
}

class Animals {
   public static function getAll() {
      // database query with table Dogs::TABLE...
   }
}
```

- function getAll must be static
- I know that function getAll can be abstract, but then I must rewrite it in all classes extends Animals so I need to avoid this behavior
- I don't know if using table name as CONSTANT is OK (maybe better protected class variable?), but now I can call everywhere in project this constant

Comment: Why does function getAll() need to be abstract? Who's enforcing these restrictions?

Comment: @MarkBaker probably a teacher ;)

Comment: function getAll CAN be abstract, no restriction

Comment: @W.B. no school project, I am trying to do best OOP design for my personal project

Comment: Define _"best OOP design solution"_ :). Anyway, I think the Animals class should be abstract.

Comment: Why don't you have a look at how PHP frameworks do it? For instance, have a look at Yii's [ActiveRecord](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/ActiveRecord.php) and [BaseActiveRecord](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/BaseActiveRecord.php). These sources are publicly available. Or better yet, why reinvent the wheel instead of using one of those frameworks?

Comment: I already have PHP framework. Code what I need is for united some services in project. But thank you for inspiration in Yii.

Comment: @W.B.Yii is one of the **worst** PHP frameworks ever in the history. *ActiveRecord* is anti-pattern since it encapsulates table access and adds domain logic on that. He should be better using Zend Framework 2 or Laravel at least

Comment: @ManicDepression static methods are **NOT** part of OOP paradigm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deal with database or another storage, better to abstract it, use Domain Model pattern and Repositroy Pattern. Repository incapsulate all interactions with storage for example MySql and Domain Model incapculate business logic.

Comment: Repository Pattern is about meditating over existing data mappers and domain objects. What you call here `Repository Pattern` is actually called `Data Mapper/Gateway`

Comment: Yes, Fauler call it mapper